# Not able to understand code behaviour - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I just started with python , and now I am trying to understand dictionary comprehension , but I don't get the  behaviour of the following code :

```
    data = [
             {'id': 12, 'data': '01'},
             {'id': 10, 'data': '05'},
             {'id': 11, 'data': '07'},
           ]
             { d['id']:d for d in data }.values()
```

Output :

`dict_values([{'id': 12, 'data': '01'}, {'id': 10, 'data': '05'}, {'id': 11, 'data': '07'}])`

please explain the output for the mentioned code . Why it is printing 2nd key value pair of each dictionary of data i.e. 'data':'01' and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have create list of dict

data = [
             {'id': 12, 'data': '01'},
             {'id': 10, 'data': '05'},
             {'id': 11, 'data': '07'},
           ]

If we split first statement then we will get following result.

**{ d['id']:d for d in data }**

**{10: {'data': '05', 'id': 10}, 11: {'data': '07', 'id': 11}, 12: {'data': '01', 'id': 12}}**

**d** is you first **dict** & you are creating new dict with **d[id]**

**d['id']:d ->  10: {'data': '05', 'id': 10}**

**values()** : This method returns a list of all the values available in a given dictionary.

In your example 3 dict are values.

That's why you are getting result like.

**[{'data': '05', 'id': 10}, {'data': '07', 'id': 11}, {'data': '01', 'id': 12}]**

Comment: You should use the code formatting for the code parts.

Answer (score 2):

data is an array that contains 3 dictionnaries, each one having 2 keys : "id" and "data".

What you are asking python is :

```
{ d['id']:d for d in data }
```

"Build me a dictionnary that contains 1 pair key/value for each element of my data array. Each key should be the "id" value of this element, and **each value should be the element of d itself**"

What you probably want to do is :

```
In [6]: c={ d['id']:d["data"] for d in data}

In [7]: c
Out[7]: {10: '05', 11: '07', 12: '01'
```

"Build me a dictionnary that contains 1 pair key/value for each element of my data array. Each key should be the "id" value of this element, and **each value should be the "data" value of of this element**"